# thymeleaf th:field needs to be html encoded to ensure no XSS,How to encode user entered data in the form when played back as an error

Tags: thymeleaf, xss

```
How to encode user entered data in the form when played back as an error.   The user needs to see what they entered to correct the form entry.   example that needs encoding: #$%&'()*!"+,-./:;?@[]^_`{|}~\
] th:utext will correctly show html encoded from the server.
] th:field incorrectly shows the html encoded values.  Is there a th:Ufield or some other solution.

business rule: "*non-encoded output could be vulnerable to Cross-Site Scripting which allows an attacker to run scripts inside a victim’s browser.*" 

Sample template below.
```

```
<form id="ccForm" th:action="@{/saveBankAccount}" th:object="${BankAccountBean}" method="POST"> 
    <div th:if="${error_messageDisplay == 'TRUE'}">
        <ul class="errorMessage">
          <li th:text="${error_message}">server message goes here</li> 
        </ul>   
    </div>
    <fieldset>  
        <div class="box">
            <label  #{jsp.payment.paymentAccountName}"></label>
            <input type="text" th:field="*{paymentAccountName}"  th:max="40"  />
        </div>
. . . . . 
</form>
```

Comment: _Is there a `th:Ufield` or some other solution._ - You mention `th:utext`. Is there a reason why that will not work for you? Maybe I have misunderstood the problem.

Comment: th:field connects to the form th:object.  This is a customer entered form values.   Name address etc.     How would th:ufield connect to the th:object.

Comment: OK - understood. Thank you for clarifying. I don't use Spring, so I am not familiar with how `th:field` works.